# DART custom elements (Vanilla DART without Polymer)

Tags: dart, custom-controls, custom-component

I came through DART custom elements, from dartlang.org site, [here](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.HtmlDocument#id_registerElement) and [here](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Element#id_Element-created).

If I understood correctly,this is a vanilla DART custom element, not related to Polymer custom tags.

I wrote the below code,

```dart
class CustomElement extends HtmlElement {
factory CustomElement() => new Element.tag('x-custom');

     CustomElement.created() : super.created() {
     print('CustomElement created!');
   }
}

void main() {
   document.registerElement('x-custom', CustomElement);
}
```

and got the "CustomElement created!" statement printed in the console, which means the element had been created!

my question is, what else? how can I use this customs element, and what can I do with it can I write HTML template, if yes, how?

I read [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) but unfortunately could not how to do same with DART.

any thoughts!

Comment: `I read this but unfortunately could not how to do same with DART.` What exactly was it you couldn't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was ableto write the below, which had been worked, feel I did it the long way,

1. I could not use the  tag
2. Not sure if the way I used to callback the elements in the custumElement in the correct way, as I was forced to use .append for all the items, and not sure if there is an easier way to do it.

my index.html file is

```dart
    pick a color:<input type="color" name="colorname" id="colorname"> the color you  selected is: <output id="picked-color"></output> click it !

    <div id='my-element'></div>
```

my index.dart file is:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class CustomElement extends HtmlElement {

factory CustomElement() => new Element.tag('x-custom'); 
CustomElement.created() : super.created() {   }

Element launchElement(Element o1){  

o1.onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('the input color is: ${o1.text}'));
 print('CustomElement created!');

var output = new Element.html('<div></div>');
var statement = new Element.html('<div></div>');
var bind = new Element.html('<div></div>')
         ..text='this text will be dynamically replaced by what you are entering down';
var input = new InputElement()
           ..id ='input'
           ..type ='text'
           ..placeholder='enter data here';

input.onInput.listen((e) => bind.text=input.value);


var element = new Element.html('<span>content: </span>')
          ..style.color='red';
var button = new ButtonElement()
  ..id = 'awesome'
  ..classes.add('important')
  ..onClick.listen((e) => pop(input.value))  // "Hi There!!!")
  ..text = 'Click Me man!'
  ..style.color='orange';

      statement.innerHtml="<b>I'm an x-custom-with-markup!</b> ";
      output.node..add(statement)..add(bind)..add(input)..add(element)..add(button);

      return (output);  
}

var button1 = new ButtonElement()
            ..id = 'awesome2'
          ..text = 'External Click Me man!';

void pop(i){ window.alert("input is: $i");  }

}

void main() {
         document.registerElement('x-custom', CustomElement); 
         var xFoo = new Element.tag('x-custom');

         InputElement colorname = querySelector('#colorname');
         Element theColor = querySelector('#picked-color');
         xFoo = xFoo.launchElement(theColor);
         theColor.text = colorname.value;

         Element myDiv=querySelector('#my-element');   
         myDiv.children.add(xFoo);


         colorname.onInput.listen((Event e) {
         theColor.text = colorname.value;   
    });  
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what Polymer was made for - to avoid such a mess of code - sorry no offence meant ;-). I understand that its an exciting challenge to do it 'manually' for the learning experience though.

Comment: understood, I like to understand the basics/fundamentals of what I'm doing/using, thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you please update the example to use window.customElements.define instead of document.registerElement as the latter one is deprecated. Does dart actually support the 'Custom Elements V1' spec?  I couldn't get it to work. Another weird issue i had developing using the webdev cli was not being able to use the new dartdevc compiler. Using dart2js everything worked fine (besides the expected deprication warning).

Comment: I remember there was an issue created in the Dart Github repo about that, I guess about a year ago. I don't know if it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is also used by Polymer. Polymer is just the combination of Custom Element, HTML Imports, Template, Polymer, Polyfills and some builerplate to connect these parts and provider a nice API.
If you want to reinvent the wheel you can go with CustomElement alone.

Change your main to

```dart
void main() {
   document.registerElement('x-custom', CustomElement);
   var elem = new Element.tag('x-element');
   elem.appendText('x-element');
   document.body.append(elem);
   elem.onClick.listen((e) {
     print('clicked');
   });
}
```

and you can react to click events

Comment: Understood, but how can I define the CallBck, and OnClick.listen,,, ... any simple code example. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not available now

- `document.registerElement` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement
- `window.customElements.define` with Dart is blocked by https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35829